# How embed H2 console into WAR

Tags: java, h2, war

My web application is not using spring boot. It's a maven web application created by netbeans with few JAX-WS services inside. It's hosted on tomcat.

Is it possible to embed H2 console into my WAR?
For example my web application is accessible on path:

```
http://host:post/myapp
```

I would like to access H2 console this way:

```
http://host:post/myapp/h2-console
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

As far as the documentation/sourcecode tells, there is a servlet class that does the trick for you [org.h2.server.web.WebServlet](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/blob/master/h2/src/main/org/h2/server/web/WebServlet.java), which you can define in your web.xml.

Ex.

```xml
.
.
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>H2Console</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.h2.server.web.WebServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>H2Console</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/console/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
.
.
```

Or based on how the framework you're using registers servlets.

This should allow you to :

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=console/" />
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, 'll try it.